# Temperature Converter

Tags: code-golf, conversion

This is a byte sized challenge where you have to convert an input temperature in one of the three units (Celsius, Kelvin and Fahrenheit) to the other two.

## Input

You would be provided with a temperature as a number followed by a unit (separated by space). The temperature can be an integer or a floating point number (23 vs 23.0 or 23.678).

You can submit a function or a full program that reads the space separated string from STDIN/ARGV/function argument or the closest equivalent and prints the output to STDOUT or closest equivalent.

## Output

Your output should be the temperature converted to the other two formats, separated by a newline and followed by the corresponding unit character on each line (optionally separated by a space). The order of the two units does not matter.

**Output precision**

- The converted number should be accurate to at least 4 decimal places without rounding.
- Trailing zeroes or decimal places are optional as long as first 4 decimal places (without rounding) are precise. You can also skip the 4 zeroes and/or the decimal point in case the actual answer has 4 zeroes after the decimal point.
- There should not be any leading zeroes
- Any number format is acceptable as long as it fulfills the above three requirements.

## Unit representation

Unit of temperature can only be one of the following:

- `C` for Celsius
- `K` for Kelvin
- `F` for Fahrenheit

## Examples

Input:

```
23 C
```

Output:

```
73.4 F
296.15 K
```

Input:

```
86.987 F
```

Output:

```
303.6983 K
30.5483 C
```

Input:

```
56.99999999 K
```

Output:

```
-216.1500 C
-357.0700 F
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest entry in bytes wins! Happy Golfing!

## Leaderboard

```html
<script>site = 'meta.codegolf',postID = 5314,isAnswer = true,QUESTION_ID = 50740</script><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script>jQuery(function(){var u='https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/';if(isAnswer)u+='answers/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJeRCD';else u+='questions/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJO6t)';jQuery.get(u,function(b){function d(s){return jQuery('<textarea>').html(s).text()};function r(l){return new RegExp('<pre class="snippet-code-'+l+'\\b[^>]*><code>([\\s\\S]*?)<\\/code><\/pre>')};b=b.items[0].body;var j=r('js').exec(b),c=r('css').exec(b),h=r('html').exec(b);if(c!==null)jQuery('head').append(jQuery('<style>').text(d(c[1])));if (h!==null)jQuery('body').append(d(h[1]));if(j!==null)jQuery('body').append(jQuery('<script>').text(d(j[1])))})})</script>
```

Comment: I assume the outputs can be in any order. Is it acceptable for all three formats to be output, for example `23C\n73.4F\n296.15K `? or must the input format be supressed?

Comment: @steveverrill the order bit is mentioned in the output section. You have to only output the other two formats.

Comment: About output precision: `2/3` => `0.666666666666` is accurate to the 4th digits? (I'd say YES). Or should it be `0.6667`?

Comment: @edc65 `0.666666666666` is correct. I am enforcing a no-rounding based precision. so `0.6666` is the alternative.

Comment: @edc65 infact, if you actually need rounding, `0.66667` is correct as well as rounded for you.

Comment: Another minor point I think it would be useful to specify in the question the formulas to be used. I've checked and it seems the formulas you are using are correct according to modern definitions. The strange thing is that VSMOW ("standard" water of a specific isotopic composition) does not freeze at exactly 0C or boil at exactly 100C. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius

Comment: mmm I dont'get the no-rounding part. 0.6667 is a better approximation than 0.6666 to the actual rational number 2/3. It's not a rounding

Comment: @edc65 Better in terms of closeness - yes, but here, I am just bothered about correctness to first 4 decimal places. Keeping that in mind, `0.66667` is an even better approximation, right ?

Comment: @steveverrill Nice point, but I actually want to avoid providing the formulas as well in the question, as then it would be simply "Program this formula" question. Too much spoon feeding.

Comment: No validation of less than absolute zero?

Comment: One of the answers does not print a space between temperature and unit. The output rules don't seem to require it, but all the examples say otherwise. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Dennis in the output, there is no rule to print the space or not. But it will be present in the input.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## CJam, <s>77</s> <s>65</s> <s>60</s> <s>59</s> <s>55</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```
l~2|"459.67+1.8/'K 273.15-'C 1.8*32+'F"S/m<{~N2$}%6<
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l~2%7C%22459.67%2B1.8%2F'K%20273.15-'C%201.8*32%2B'F%22S%2Fm%3C%7B~N2%24%7D%256%3C&input=23%20C).

#### How it works

```
l~    e# Read and evaluate the input: F, K, C -> 15, 20, 12
2|    e# Bitwise OR with 2: F, K, C -> 15, 22, 14 = 0, 1, 2 (mod 3)

"459.67+1.8/'K 273.15-'C 1.8*32+'F"S/

      e# Push ["459.67+1.8/K" "273.15-C" "1.8*32+F"].
      e# These commands convert from F to K, K to C and C to F.

m<    e# Rotate the array of commands by 15, 22 or 14 units to the left.
{     e# For each command:
  ~   e#     Execute it.
  N   e#     Push a linefeed.
  2$  e#     Copy the temperature for the next iteration.
}%    e# Collect all results in an array.
6<    e# Keep only the first 8 elements.
```

Answer (score 32):

## Python 3, <s>118</s> 116 bytes

```py
I=input()
t=eval(I[:-1])
u=ord(I[-1])%7
exec("u=-~u%3;t=[t*1.8-459.67,(t-32)/1.8,t+273.15][u];print(t,'FCK'[u]);"*2)
```

Performs the conversions in a rotary order `K -> F -> C -> K` twice.

Comment: Gotta love `'FCK'[u]`.

Comment: Haha what the heck, guys. Upvote the question and answers, not my dumb comment. :P

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (*ES6*), 127  <s>130 132</s> bytes

Waiting for some amazing esolanguage answer, I did not find much to golf here.

Using template string, the  3 newlines are significant and counted.

Run snippet in Firefox to test.

```js
F=x=>([t,u]=x.split(' '),z=273.15,y=9/5,u<'F'?`${t*y+32} F
${+t+z} K`:u<'K'?`${t=(t-32)/y} C
${t+z} K`:`${t-=z} C
${t*y+32} F`)

// Predefined tests

;['23 C','86.987 F','56.99999999 K']
.forEach(v=>O.innerHTML += v+' ->\n'+F(v)+'\n\n')
```

```html
<input id=I><button onclick='O.innerHTML=F(I.value)'>-></button><br>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 7):

## Pip, <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```
Ft"CFK"RMbP(a-(o:[32i273.15]Ab%7))*$/95@A[tb]+(oAt%7).s.t
```

Takes input from command-line arguments.

Formatted and slightly ungolfed:

```
o:[32 0 273.15]
F t ("CFK" RM b)
  P (a - o@(Ab % 7))
    * "95"@At / "95"@Ab
    + o@(At%7)
    . s . t
```

**Explanation:**

The general conversion formula between unit 1 and unit 2 is `temp2 = (temp1 - offset1) * mult2 / mult1 + offset2`. The offsets could be to absolute zero or to any other convenient temperature; let's use 0 °C.

```
Unit Mult Offset
C    5    0     
K    5    273.15
F    9    32
```

We'll build lists of these values and index into them based on which unit we're dealing with. Pip doesn't have associative arrays/hashes/dictionaries, so we need to convert the characters into integer indices. Maybe there will be helpful patterns with the ASCII values.

```
Unit Asc A%2 Mult A%7 A%7%3 Offset
C    67  1   5    4   1     0
K    75  1   5    5   2     273.15
F    70  0   9    0   0     32
```

This looks promising. One more useful fact: indices in Pip wrap around. So we don't actually need the `%3` as long as we're indexing into something of length 3. Defining `o:[32 0 273.15]` and using `(o (Ab)%7)` will do the trick. (`A` gets the ASCII value of a character. The `(l i)` syntax is used for indexing into iterables, as well as for function calls.)

For the multipliers, we only need the two numbers 9 and 5. Since numbers are the same as strings in Pip, and thus are indexable, getting the multiplier is as simple as `95@Ab` (using the other method of indexing, the `@` operator).

Using Pip's array-programming features, we can save a character over the naive method:

```
95@At/95@Ab
$/95@A[tb]    Make a list of t and b, apply 95@A(...) to each item, and fold on /
```

Finally, add the offset for the new unit, concatenate a space and the new unit's symbol onto the end, and print.

We do this for each `t` in `"CFK" RM b`, thus converting to each unit except the original.

**Sample invocation:**

```
C:\Golf> pip.py tempConv.pip 86.987 F
30.548333333333332 C
303.6983333333333 K
```

(For more on Pip, see [the repository](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip).)

Answer (score 6):

## dc, 102 bytes

I'm pretty sure this can be golfed more, but here's a start:

```
4k[9*5/32+dn[ F
]n]sf[459.67+5*9/dn[ K
]n]sk[273.15-1/dn[ C
]n]sc[rlfxlkxq]sC[lkxlcxq]sF?dC=CF=Flcxlfx
```

dc barely makes the grade on this one.  Specifically dc string handling isn't really up to the job.  But all we need to do is differentiate between "C", "F" and "K".  Fortunately dc parses "C" and "F" as hex numerals 12 and 15.  And fo "K" it just leaves 0 on the stack.

#### Output:

```
$ dc -f tempconv.dc <<< "23 C"
73.4000 F
296.1500 K
$ dc -f tempconv.dc <<< "86.987 F"
303.6983 K
30.5483 C
$ dc -f tempconv.dc <<< "56.99999999 K"
-216.1500 C
-357.0700 F
$
```

Answer (score 5):

### C, 160 bytes

```c
float v,f[]={1,1.8,1},d[]={0,32,273.15};u,t,j;main(){scanf("%f %c",&v,&u);for(u=u/5-13,v=(v-d[u])/f[u];j<2;)t=(++j+u)%3,printf("%f %c\n",f[t]*v+d[t],"CFK"[t]);}
```

This reads from stdin. No output precision is specified, so it prints whatever `printf()` feels like printing, which is mostly more than 4 digits.

Ungolfed version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

float v, f[] = {1.0f, 1.8f, 1.0f}, d[] = {0.0f, 32.0f, 273.15f};
char u;
int t, j;

int main() {
    scanf("%f %c", &v, &u);
    u = u / 5 - 13;
    v = (v - d[u]) / f[u];
    for( ; j < 2; ) {
        t = (++j + u) % 3;
        printf("%f %c\n", f[t] * v + d[t], "CFK"[t]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Some explanations/remarks:

- This is based on lookup tables `f` and `d` that contains the multiplication factors and offsets to convert Celsius to any other unit (including Celsius itself, to avoid special cases).
- If `u` is the input unit, `u / 5 - 13` maps `C` to 0, `F` to 1, and `K` to 2.
- Input is always converted to Celsius.
- Loop iterates over the two units that are not the input, and converts the Celsius value to that unit.
- The golfed version uses an `int` variable instead of a `char` variable to receive the `scanf()` input. This is a type mismatch, which will only produce correct results on little endian machines (which is almost all of them these days).

Comment: Shortened to 152: `float v,f[]={1,1.8,1,0,32,273.15};u;main(j){scanf("%f %c",&v,&u);for(u=u/4&3,v-=f[u+3],v/=f[u];j++<3;printf("%f %c\n",f[u]*v+f[u+3],"CFK"[u]))u++,u%=3;}`. Gained a bit with fewer variables, moving code around. New assumption is argc=1 (j=1). `u = u/4 & 3`.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 168 Bytes

I saw the Python 3 solution just as I was about to post this, but whatever, I'm just practicing golfing.

```py
s=raw_input().split();v=eval(s[0]);c,t=(v-32)/1.8,v-273.15
print[["%fC\n%fF"%(t,t*1.8+32),"%fK\n%fC"%(c+273.15,c)][s[1]=="F"],"%fK\n%fF"%(v+273.15,v*1.8+32)][s[1]=="C"]
```

Ungolfed:

```py
def conv(s):
    s = s.split()
    v = float(s[0])
    if s[1]=="C":
        print "%f K\n%f F"%(v+273.15,v*1.8+32)
    elif s[1]=="F":
        v = (v-32)/1.8
        print "%f K\n%f C"%(v+274.15,v)
    else:
        c = v-273.15
        print "%f C\n%f F"%(c,c*1.8+32)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, <s>85 80</s> 76

```
#!perl -nl
print$_=/C/?$_+273.15." K":/K/?$_*9/5-459.67." F":5/9*($_-32)." C"for$_,$_
```

Test [me](http://ideone.com/40j1HI).

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>161</s> 153

```
function f($i){list($v,$u)=split(" ",$i);$u==C||print($v=$u==K?$v-273.15:($v-32)*5/9)."C\n";$u!=K&&print $v+273.15 ."K\n";$u!=F&&print $v*9/5+32 ."F\n";}
```

http://3v4l.org/CpvG7

<s>Would be nice to golf out two more characters to get in the top ten...</s>

Comment: Well technically, based on the rules, there doesn't need to be spaces between the unit and it's temperature in the output. By my calculation that saves 3 bytes.

Comment: Good point :-)  I also found a way to reuse a variable, which saves another handful.

Comment: 135 byte long solution: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/303e4c29d9f50e4a5af6e72fff9a39ad7041d454. Basically: removed the `\n` and changed into real newlines, converted into a full program (receiving the data over GET, eg: `http://localhost/my_file.php?t=<temperature>`) and replaced `$u!=K` with `$u^K` and `$u!=F` with `$u^F`. If `$u` is `K`, running `$u^K` will return an empty string, which is a falsy value. Also, your space inside the split was converted into `C^c` (Just to look cool).

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 167

```py
s=raw_input();i=eval(s.split()[0]);d={"C":"%f K\n%f F"%(i+273,32+i*1.8),"K":"%f C\n%f F"%(i-273,i*1.8-459.4),"F":"%f C\n%f K"%(i/1.8-17.78,i/1.8+255.2)};print d[s[-1]]`
```

This is my first try on CodeGolf.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. This is a nice attempt for the very first golf! I have added some sugar to your post by correcting formatting and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 126 bytes

```
AYZczdJvY=Y*JK1.8
?%"%f F\n%f K",+32Y+J273.15qZ"C"?%"%f F\n%f C",-Y459.67-J273.15qZ"K"?%"%f C\n%f K",c-J32K*+J459.67c5 9qZ"F"
```

This feels really long to me...oh well.

Comment: There's a Python solution shorter than this :P

Comment: @orlp I know, I know...

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>150</s> <s>144</s> 141 bytes

```
a=scan(,"");U=c("C","K","F");i=which(U==a[2]);Z=273.15;x=scan(t=a[1]);cat(paste(c(C<-c(x,x-Z,5*(x-32)/9)[i],C+Z,32+C*9/5)[-i],U[-i]),sep="\n")
```

Indented, with new lines:

```
a=scan(,"")
U=c("C","K","F")
i=which(U==a[2])
Z=273.15
x=as.double(a[1])
cat(paste(c(C<-c(x,x-Z,5*(x-32)/9)[i],C+Z,32+C*9/5)[-i],
            U[-i]),
    sep="\n")
```

Usage:

```
> a=scan(,"");U=c("C","K","F");i=which(U==a[2]);Z=273.15;x=scan(t=a[1]);cat(paste(c(C<-c(x,x-Z,5*(x-32)/9)[i],C+Z,32+C*9/5)[-i],U[-i]),sep="\n")
1: 23 C
3: 
Read 2 items
Read 1 item
296.15 K
73.4 F
> a=scan(,"");U=c("C","K","F");i=which(U==a[2]);Z=273.15;x=scan(t=a[1]);cat(paste(c(C<-c(x,x-Z,5*(x-32)/9)[i],C+Z,32+C*9/5)[-i],U[-i]),sep="\n")
1: 56.9999999 K
3: 
Read 2 items
Read 1 item
-216.1500001 C
-357.07000018 F
> a=scan(,"");U=c("C","K","F");i=which(U==a[2]);Z=273.15;x=scan(t=a[1]);cat(paste(c(C<-c(x,x-Z,5*(x-32)/9)[i],C+Z,32+C*9/5)[-i],U[-i]),sep="\n")
1: 86.987 F
3: 
Read 2 items
Read 1 item
30.5483333333333 C
303.698333333333 K
```

Thanks to @AlexA. & @MickyT. !

Comment: Nice work. You can save a byte using `as.double()` rather than `as.numeric()`.

Comment: I think the `switch` statement can be done with `c(x,x-273.15,5*(x-32)/9)[i]` for 4 characters

Comment: Thanks! Actually, prior to version 3.0, I could have shorten it more with as.real() instead of as.numeric(), but the function is defunct now.

Comment: Another saving would be replacing `as.double(a[1])` with `scan(t=a[1])`.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>206</s> <s>193</s> <s>187</s> <s>175</s> <s>162</s> <s>159</s> 156

```js
e=273.15,a=prompt(f=1.8).split(" "),b=+a[0],X=b-32,c=a[1];alert(c=="F"&&(X/f+"C\n"+(X/f+e+"K"))||(c=="C"?b*f+32+"‌​F\n"+(b+e+"K"):b*f-459.67+"F\n"+(b-e+"C")))
```

Thanks goes to Optimizer and Ismael Miguel for helping me golf it a little further.

Comment: You can save a few bytes by converting the `if` `else` to `?:`

Comment: You could save a few more by combining your `if ... return; return ?:` to a `return ?: ?:`

Comment: You can save 1 byte replacing `a=prompt().split(" "),e=273.15,f=1.8;alert([...]` with `a=prompt(e=273.15,f=1.8).split(" "),alert([...]`. Also, you can remove the spaces after the unit. Also, removing the `return` and moving the `alert` inside the function reduced a lot! And instead of setting `a`, just use the `apply()` method with the split. But here you go: `(function(b,c){alert(c=="F"&&((b-32)/f+"C\n"+((b-32)/f+e+"K"))||(c=="C"?b*f+32+"F\n"+(b+e+"K"):b*f-459.67+"F\n"+(b-e+"C")))}).apply(e=273.15,prompt(f=1.8).split(" "))`! 166 bytes (**-21** bytes). Ping me in the chat if you have doubts.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: a[0] needs to be cast to a number, it doesn't work right otherwise. I'll look into the other stuff you suggested though.

Comment: You can add `b+=0;` inside the function, before the `alert`.

Comment: That wouldn't work, but I found a solution that does.

Comment: This one works for me: `(function(b,c){b/=1;alert(c=="F"&&((b-32)/f+"C\n"+((b-32)/f+e+"K"))||(c=="C"?b*f+32+"F\n"+(b+e)+"K":b*f-459.67+"F\n"+(b-e)+"C"))}).apply(e=273.15,prompt(f=1.8).split(" "))` (171 bytes).

Comment: And this one too: `(function(b,c){alert(c=="F"&&((b-32)/f+"C\n"+((b-32)/f+e+"K"))||(c=="C"?b*f+32+"F\n"+(+b+e)+"K":b*f-459.67+"F\n"+(b-e)+"C"))}).apply(e=273.15,prompt(f=1.8).split(" "))` (167 bytes).

Comment: I just got it down to 162 anyway.

Comment: You can chop it down to 159 if you remove the spaces after the units.

Comment: You're right, I missed some of the spaces. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: 154 bytes: `e=273.15,a=prompt(f=1.8).split(" "),b=+a[0],X=b-32/f,c=a[1];alert(c=="F"&&(X+"C\n"+(X+e+"K"))||(c=="C"?b*f+32+"F\n"+(b+e+"K"):b*f-459.67+"F\n"+(b-e+"C")))`

Comment: Sorry, edited my comment on the wrong time. But I've reduced it a little bit

Comment: Your last edit doesn't work right.

Comment: You are right. But Now I can't edit it.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 66

Hopefully correct this time.

```
Print[1##]&@@@Reduce[F==1.8K-459.67&&C==K-273.15&&#==#2,,#2];&@@#&
```

Example

```
%[37 C]   (* % represents the function above *)
```

> 310.15 K
>
> 98.6 F

Comment: The OP said in a comment that "You have to only output the other two formats."

Comment: @Thomas That and other problems (hopefully) fixed.  Not very good but I am losing interest.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 239 bytes

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="C",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)+273.15&"K
"&9*LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)/5+32&"F",IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="K",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)-273.15&"C
"&(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)*9/5-459.67&"F",(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)+459.67)*5/9&"K
"&(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)-32)*5/9&"C"))
```

112 bytes of which are used to seperate Value and Unit.  Anybody know a better solution?